# Get String value of json array in a json

Tags: java, json

For the below Json payload I'am trying to get the first array element of **email_address**.
However using the below code I get email address but with the array bracket and quotes like: `["test@test.com"]`.
I need only the email address text. First element array.

Payload:

```
{
   "valid":{
      "email_addresses":[
         "testauto@test.com"
      ]  
   }
}
```

Code:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new FileReader(jsonfilepath));
JSONObject jsonObjects = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonObject.get("valid").toString());
String email = jsonObjects.get("email_addresses").toString();
System.out.println("Email address:"+email);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this unitTest could help you

```
   @Test
   public void test() throws JSONException, FileNotFoundException {
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(new FileInputStream(new File(jsonfilepath))));
      JSONObject valid = (JSONObject) json.get("valid");
      Object emailAdresses = valid.get("email_addresses");
      if (emailAdresses instanceof JSONArray) {
         JSONArray emailAdressArray = (JSONArray) emailAdresses;
         Object firstEmailAdress = emailAdressArray.get(0);
         System.out.println(firstEmailAdress.toString());
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [JSONArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) to get the array values:

```
JSONArray emailAddresses = (JSONArray) jsonObjects.get("email_addresses");
String email = emailAddresses.getJSONObject(0).toString()
System.out.println("Email address: " + email);
```

Even though I strongly encourage using [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse json instead of doing this way, it makes life easier.

Comment: Why are you parsing json string to json, just to convert it back to string to parse it again? `parser.parse(jsonObject.get("valid").toString())`

Comment: @rkosegi well, that part it's not the code I changed. It was in the question. But yes, it makes no sense, I'll update it

Comment: then don't put it in an answer. It's non-sense

Comment: Ok, I'll only put in the answer the code to add / update